# Biblatex - author name formatting inconsistent when multiple authors are present

Tags: biblatex

The author section of the references show:

> Homer, David and Michael Bowen-Jones (2014).....

While what I wish for it to show is:

> Homer, David and Bowen-Jones, Michael (2014)....

How do I change this?

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex} % Referencing
\bibliography{test.bib}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}

@book{homer,
    author = {Homer, David and Bowen-Jones, Michael},
    title = {IB Physics Course Book: 2014 Edition: Oxford IB Diploma Program},
    publisher = {Oxford University Press},
    date = {2014-04},
    edition = {1},
    location = {Oxford}
}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography
\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
 \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
```

you can change the format of the primary name associated with an entry.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex} % Referencing

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{homer,
  author    = {Homer, David and Bowen-Jones, Michael},
  title     = {IB Physics Course Book: 2014 Edition: Oxford IB Diploma Program},
  publisher = {Oxford University Press},
  date      = {2014-04},
  edition   = {1},
  location  = {Oxford}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Note that `\bibliography` needs the file name *without* the file extension, I prefer `\addbibresource` where the file extension is mandatory. I also used `\DeclareDelimFormat` to redefine `nameyeardelim`.

> Homer, David and Bowen-Jones, Michael (Apr. 2014). *IB Physics Course Book: 2014 Edition: Oxford IB Diploma Program.* 1st ed. Oxford: Oxford University Press.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you! Could I ask why using `\DeclareDelimFormat` is preferred over `\renewcommand`? A warning appears with your method, stating ' Package biblatex Warning: Delimiter 'nameyeardelim' in context '' already defined, overwriting on input line 16.', but does not hinder compilation.

Comment: @GeorgeTian I prefer `\DeclareDelimFormat` because `nameyeardelim` is a context-sensitive delimiter now and context-sensitive delimiters should be redefined with `\DeclareDelimFormat` (you could for example define a different behaviour for `\cite` and `\parencite` with this new interface). The warning you get is harmless and can be ignored, in fact newer versions of `biblatex` do not issue a warning about this any more.